# Font Family for email on Outlook Windows not applying

Tags: html, css, outlook

I know this has been asked everywhere online and I've exhausted most of the solutions I've come across. I am trying to set the `font-family` on all of the elements within the body of an email.

It works across everything fine (Outlook Mac, Gmail, Yahoo) using this `CSS`:

```
<style>
    body, table, td {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;}
</style>
```

but not on Outlook Windows...

I tried to set the `font-family` inline on every single element in my email like the snippet below and it's still reverting to Times New Roman. Any advice on this would be much appreciated.

```
<h2><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">EMAIL HEADING TEXT&nbsp;GOES HERE</span></h2>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, you need to wrap your style for MS Outlook. For more details click [here](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/982-outlook-overrides-font-to-times-new-roman)

```
<!--[if mso]>
<style type="text/css">
body, table, td {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap your `style` like this

```
<!--[if !mso]>
<style type=”text/css”>
    body, table, td {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

as i remember outlook will fallback to `time new roman` if you use `style`